# Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object, jsonwebtoken

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt

I am going to create a token of form data using `jsonwebtoken` in my React project.

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

const MyForm = () => {
    const submitForm = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();
       const data = { name: 'name', email: 'email', subject: 'subject', message: 'message' };
       const token = jwt.sign(data, 'qwerty');
       console.log(token);
    }
    return(
        <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
            ...
        </form>
    );
}
export default MyForm;
```

Following error is occurred.

```
TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
push../node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js.module.exports [as sign]
../node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:108
  105 |   return failure(new Error('secretOrPrivateKey must have a value'));
  106 | }
  107 | 
> 108 | if (secretOrPrivateKey != null && !(secretOrPrivateKey instanceof KeyObject)) {
      | ^  109 |   try {
  110 |     secretOrPrivateKey = createPrivateKey(secretOrPrivateKey)
  111 |   } catch (_) {
View compiled
submitEmail
../MyForm.js:22
  19 |    e.preventDefault();
  20 |    
  21 |    const data = { name: 'name', email: 'email', subject: 'subject', message: 'message' };
> 22 |    const token = jwt.sign(data, 'qwerty');
     | ^  23 |    console.log(token)
  24 | 
  25 |
```

Why is this giving me that error?
I have tried to solve this problem but no results yet.
And any help to fix it is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just go to the npm page of [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) package you are using, open the github repo of it, open Issues tab and seek for `'instanceof' is not an object`. You will find the only 1 [issue](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/863) with a statement that `jsonwebtoken is a Node.js module, its use in a browser was never intended. Versions before 9.0.0 could use webpack's polyfill of the Node.js built-in modules.` and some additional details.

Comment: What Version of Node and the jsonwebtoken module are you using?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I had the same issue. The issue being that version 9.0.0 of the jsonwebtoken package does not support node version 11 and below, so I solved it by downgrading the version of the jsonwebtoken package.

I did so by changing the jsonwebtoken dependency **from 9.0.0 to 8.5.1** inside the package.json file, then I ran **npm update** inside my terminal.

Upgrading your node version might be recommended here, but I haven't quite managed to update my node version because of an npm issue, so this is only a workaround.

Checkout the following article explaining the migration from v8 to v9 of the jsonwebtoken package.
https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/wiki/Migration-Notes:-v8-to-v9

Comment: But version <9.0.0 are a security issue, so we must update to 9.0.0 of jsonwebtoken

Comment: Got the same error with node v16

Comment: This just solved it for me. THANK YOU!

Comment: @Orelsanpls Are you sure that you haven't installed node twice and that your older node version gets prioritized over your newer installation? 

After closing your terminal, does `node -v` still issue 16.x?  I would suggest deleting node completely and to then download it with nvm. 

Here's a guide going over the nvm installation in detail: https://heynode.com/tutorial/install-nodejs-locally-nvm/

Comment: @92lexus I have the same situation with Orelsanpls.
Actually, I am currently using node v16 and jsonwebtoken v9.
But getting the same error. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer.  I have several installed versions of npm (via the nvm) and I needed to switch to a newer one.

Answer (score 1):

`jsonwebtoken` is a Node module. In other words, it does not work on browsers very well. See this [issue here.](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/863) [This page](https://jwt.io/libraries?language=JavaScript) offers good alternatives for client-side jwt operations.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to use the latest node version, so please first check your node version this error can get in version `10.*.*`

So update your Nodejs version

Answer (score 0):

In the latest jsonwebtoken, v9:
might want to try...

```
let secret = 'qwerty';
const token = jwt.sign(data, secret.toString('utf-8'));
```

additionally, you may need to add params to force older behavior...

```
const token = jwt.sign(data, secret.toString('utf-8'), { algorithm: 'HS256', allowInsecureKeySizes: true, allowInvalidAsymmetricKeyTypes: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well. Nothing suggested so far worked for me until I also made this change to use require statement rather than an import.

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, I was using node version v10.16.0, I uninstalled it and download node version v18.16.0. Then it works well

Answer (score -1):

I experienced a similar issue with the verify module, verifying in the frontend the issue was with the apikey. It didnt correspond with the apikey at the backend

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34698864)