# How to import @types definitions with bun js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, bun

Bun works fine with TypeScript libraries, but I can't get it working with packages that require `@types`, such as `jsonwebtoken`.

For example for the following code

```
import {sign} from "jsonwebtoken";

const token = sign({ name: "name" }, "secret");
console.log(token);
```

I get error

```
103 | 
104 |   if (!secretOrPrivateKey && options.algorithm !== 'none') {
105 |     return failure(new Error('secretOrPrivateKey must have a value'));
106 |   }
107 | 
108 |   if (secretOrPrivateKey != null && !(secretOrPrivateKey instanceof KeyObject)) {
                                         ^
TypeError: Right hand side of instanceof is not an object
      at /Users/huakun/Desktop/bunapp/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:108:38
      at /Users/huakun/Desktop/bunapp/bunbun.ts:3:14
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object, jsonwebtoken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74907805/right-hand-side-of-instanceof-is-not-an-object-jsonwebtoken)

Answer (score 0):

Bun doesn't support the installation of types packages directly. You have to use either npm or yarn to install the types package in your project

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jsonwebtoken
```

or

```
yard add --dev @types/jsonwebtoken
```

After installing the types, you can import and use the jsonwebtoken package in your TypeScript files, and you'll have access to the types

Comment: The error in the post is a **runtime error**.