# jwtSign fails with TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jwt

```js
const secret = 'qwerty'
const data = {
  name: 'name',
  email: 'email',
  subject: 'subject',
  message: 'message'
}
const accessToken = jwt.sign(data, secret.toString('utf-8'), {
  algorithm: 'HS256',
  allowInsecureKeySizes: true,
  allowInvalidAsymmetricKeyTypes: true,
  expiresIn: '500s'
})
```

Working with Nextjs. I keep running into this error :

> TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object

I read the solution posted [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74907805/right-hand-side-of-instanceof-is-not-an-object-jsonwebtoken)
I upgraded everything to the latest, also deleted node_modules, ran npm install and restarted npm run dev but have the same errors:

grep jsonwebtoken package.json

```
"jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0", 
"@types/jsonwebtoken": "9.0.1",
```

node --version v19.6.0

It's been over a day now, I can really do with some help here!

Comment: did you tryied to downgrade jsonwebtoken to 8.5.1 ?

Comment: I don't see problem in your current code, you should add code more.

Comment: I started typing...yes, I also tried to downgrade jsonwebtoken to 8.5.1, same error. But I decided to try it again. Anyway, the short version is that downgrading jsonwebtoken worked (and reworking the sign() signature worked. It isn't an ideal solution, since I need to live with the vuln. but I am good to proceed for now. 

If anyone has any suggestions on any fixes for jsonwebtoken 9.0