# Error generating JWT with jsonwebtoken library in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jwt, backend

I am trying to generate a JWT token i am getting "TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object"   although syntax is correct.

```
const jsonwebtoken = require("jsonwebtoken");
 const JWT_SECRET = "goK!pusp6ThEdURUtRenOwUhAsWUCLheBazl!uJLPlS8EbreWLdrupIwabRAsiBu";
 console.log(jsonwebtoken.sign({ user: "admin" }, JWT_SECRET))
```

is there any issue with jsonwebtoken module?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY91A.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found another post that talks about this issue: [Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object, jsonwebtoken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74907805/right-hand-side-of-instanceof-is-not-an-object-jsonwebtoken).

Basically in that post the answer says that the problem is caused by `jsonwebtoken` and `node.js` versions not being compatible. What you can do is try upgrading your `node.js` or downgrading the `jsonwebtoken` dependency to a lower version.